How can I clear the terminal window in Visual Studio code in Python to show only the output without the path/prompt?
I only need the output of my Python code, without any details in the terminal window, such as the path or the prompt.
I tried to open the code Runner extension, then clicked on Extensions settings, the Executor Map, and Edit in settings.json and I changed from python: cls && python -u, to python: clear && python3 -u,
and that caused an error!
What do you think I should do?


What do you mean by "unneeded details" here? Also, why change from python to python3 if it was working?

Why not start up a cmd prompt and run your python script followed by 1>out.txt 2>&1.  Then all the output will be in out.txt

I suggest uninstalling Code Runner and just using Microsoft's Python debugger: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_configure-and-run-the-debugger. You can configure it to output everything your program outputs in the Debug Console panel, and just what your program outputs. Code Runner itself automatically prints out extra stuff.

Please [edit] to show what kind of output you are getting right now, and what kind of output do you want to see instead. Because, as mentioned, "unneeded details" is not clear.

Hello, I'm not sure what you're expecting is some information about the working directory, classpath? If "unneeded details" refers to part of the prompt. You can modify the shell file to make changes. The shell configuration file is usually located under C:path/your/usrename and is usually .bashrc or .bash_profile. Find it and modify "PS1=" (blank or set your own)".

I do not want to see that path, "C:\Users\Ahmed>," after every output, as in the picture

See How to hide file paths when running Python scripts in VS Code?. My answer there is basically repeating what I just said: stop using Code Runner and just use the regular Python debugger + Debug Console.

why  don't you use Jupiter Notebook or ipython then ?

Hello, the terminal needs a working directory when vscode is running. You can set it to a different path. You can add "cwd": "${yoursetting}" to the task.json file. Then create a task by typing Task: Run Task into the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P). Or you can choose to run it with a jupyter notebook.

Yes, thanks to all of you—Gino Mempin, Hujaakbar, and Jeanneli—I tried your solutions, and they've worked.

Hello, I'm so happy I can help you. I try to edit and publish the answer, and you can set it as an answer if you can. This may be helpful to other members who are having similar problems, thank you very much.

Please, @Jeanneli, Can you tell me how I can set it as an answer?.

you can set it to a different path. You can add "cwd": "${yoursetting}" to the task.json file. Then create a task by typing Task: Run Task into the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P). Or you can choose to run it with a jupyter notebook. Additionally, you can use the Debug Console to display the output. You'll need to change the settings in the.vscode/launch.json file and set the console configuration to internalConsole.You can set it up like this:

